# JPA Query to get entity type

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, jpql, datanucleus

I am trying to write a JPA query to get the type for a particular entity, given the id of the entity. I have an abstract class Account, and concrete subclasses CustomerAccount and AdministratorAccount. The id is an attribute of the Account, so I am trying to construct a query to return the Type (i.e. foo.bar.CustomerAccount) given the ID of the account.

I tried the following:

```
String sql = "SELECT TYPE(a) from Account a where a.id = :userId";
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? I'm using the google app engine jpa implementation (datanucleus) if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, FWIW you are using Google's JPA plugin which just happens to use some ancient jars provided by the DataNucleus project. You are not using DataNucleus JPA.

Secondly, the datastore "GAE/Datastore" and Google's JPA plugin are not likely to support JPQL "TYPE" since that came along after their plugin was developed.

Finally, you maybe would get the info you want in a more efficient way by just doing

```
Object obj = em.find(Account.class, id);
Class type = obj.getClass();
```

since this also inspects the L1/L2 caches

Comment: Your post makes sense, my thinking was that it would be inefficient to retrieve the entire entity from the persistence tier since that can be large, but if this is the way to go I'll give it a shot